# Replace Content Here

Tags: html, xhtml

Ok so on W3Schools, it has the image below. Is there a way to keep the outer orange/yellow part and simply replace the "Content goes here" by doing `src="somehtmlpage.html"` which contains only a body or whatever?

[image]
I know I can do it with a Frame/IFrame but I read somewhere that Frames aren't good or something like that.. Any ideas?

Comment: Why downvote.. it's a legit question :S

Comment: Have a `<textarea>` that you can enter code and then have a `<div>` where you use JS to set `<div>.innerHTML=<textarea>`?  I'm unsure what your question is exactly...

Comment: I want to keep the outer orange/yellow part but replace the grey part with another page/html file. So that all pages have the same layout and if I change the outer orange part on one, it changes on all.. My question was how to do that but I guess no one likes it.. My current site looks like: http://brandon-t.github.io/ArtOfCPlusPlus/Cpp01.html but I have to constantly copy the code from one page to another and replace the content area..

Comment: Isn't that basically the reason CSS came to be?

Comment: I imagine people are downvoting because there is no code (which shows prior effort) and you mention W3Schools but do not provide a link to the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, frames are not a good idea, but if you want an html solution that's what you have to use.

However, you can load content into that div using javascript.  I recommend using jQuery's `.load()` method for this task, as it will streamline the process for you and allow you to select specific content from the source file.

Answer (score 0):

There are Pros ad cons of usig frames

**Pros**

1. Ability to keep one part of the page static whilst changing
   another part. For this reason frames are often used for navigation
   menus.
2. Frames can also help reduce bandwidth and server load, because
   the same content does not need to be loaded every time a new page is
   visited.

**Cons**

1. A broken frameset happens when the frames are not loaded or
   displayed correctly.
2. Search engines don't deal with frames well.
3. You can't link directly to a framed page.
4. The same problems related to links also apply to bookmarking pages.

Iframes can e give a trial. It works well too for some limits

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery load function to load data from a HTML file in a specific element

see the link below

[Jquery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some html code from a different file, you could use php include

```
<?php include('somehtmlpage.html'); ?>
```

Dont forget to rename the file index.**php** or test.**php**

eg, If you wanted to have a template and a file  for the main content:

**main.php**

```
<h1>title</h1>
<?php include('somehtmlpage.html'); ?>
```

**somehtmlpage.html**

```
<p>something...</p>
```

The page will look like this:

> ## Title
>
> something...